# Match "\b(OneTwoThree|OneTwo|TwoThree)\b" with least repetition

Tags: regex, overlap

I managed this with PCRE only, but I'd like it to work with Javascript's RegExp as well. That, and the regex is ugly. Are there any other, saner ways of accomplishing this?

*Note, that while the topic says "OneTwoThree", I'm using "qwe" for brevity.*

```
$ cat test.txt | grep -oP '\b(q(\g<we>|\g<w>)|(?<we>(?<w>w)e))\b'
qwe
qw
we
```

File test.txt contains:

`qwe qw we q w e qq qe wq ww eq ew ee qqq qqw qqe qwq qww qeq qew qee wqq wqw wqe wwq www wwe weq wew wee eqq eqw eqe ewq eww ewe eeq eew eee`

*(Only the first three should match.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work for your sample data:

```
/\b(qwe?|we)\b/
/\b(q?we|qw)\b/
```

Which you can test [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cb%28qwe?%7Cwe%29%5Cb&input=qwe%20qw%20we%20q%20w%20e%20qq%20qe%20wq%20ww%20eq%20ew%20ee%20qqq%20qqw%20qqe%20qwq%20qww%20qeq%20qew%20qee%20wqq%20wqw%20wqe%20wwq%20www%20wwe%20weq%20wew%20wee%20eqq%20eqw%20eqe%20ewq%20eww%20ewe%20eeq%20eew%20eee).

But for the full pattern you specified in the title it would be

```
/\b(OneTwo(Three)?|TwoThree)\b/
/\b((One)?TwoThree|OneTwo)\b/
```

---

Now, this is not more readable, but it does reduce redundancy slightly:

```
/\b(?!w\b)q?we?\b/
```

Which you can test [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cb%28%3F!w%5Cb%29q%3Fwe%3F%5Cb&input=qwe%20qw%20we%20q%20w%20e%20qq%20qe%20wq%20ww%20eq%20ew%20ee%20qqq%20qqw%20qqe%20qwq%20qww%20qeq%20qew%20qee%20wqq%20wqw%20wqe%20wwq%20www%20wwe%20weq%20wew%20wee%20eqq%20eqw%20eqe%20ewq%20eww%20ewe%20eeq%20eew%20eee)

Or for your full pattern:

```
/\b(?!Two\b)(One)?Two(Three)?\b/
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like a readable regexp with no repetition, but this may be the turning point of pain vs. readability. I'll still wait a while longer for additional answers.

Comment: @Gima That's fine. Ultimately, I don't think you'll be able to do it without repeating at least two of the parts, one way or the other. However, There may be other solutions I haven't considered.

Comment: I like this one `/\b(?!w\b)q?we?\b/`

Comment: I like that one because the common 'w' can be a string, so it doesn't depend on the number of characters (like mine). And since it gets rid of the alternation it might be faster, if not more flexible. +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this but not sure -

```
 # \b(?=..)q?we?\b

 \b 
 (?= . . )
 q? w e? 
 \b
```